# Using Filewriter to write but the file remains empty.

Tags: java

I have the following code to write in three files. I have printed the Strings before writing to ensure they have some data in them, the printed Strings show the data given to them by calling this function but on creation of file the files are empty.
Please suggest something.

```
public static void save(String editedFileText,String srcFileText,String translFileText)throws IOException { 
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
System.out.println(editedFileText);
System.out.println(srcFileText);
System.out.println(translFileText);
int retrival = chooser.showSaveDialog(null);
if (retrival == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
try {
        FileWriter edit = new FileWriter(chooser.getSelectedFile()+".txt");
        edit.write(editedFileText.toString());
       FileWriter srcFile = new  FileWriter(chooser.getSelectedFile()+"_srcText"+".txt");
        srcFile.write(srcFileText.toString());
        FileWriter trans = new FileWriter(chooser.getSelectedFile()+"_translFile"+".txt");
       trans.write(translFileText.toString());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do the same thing you would do if you took a number 2.

Comment: Sir, I didn't get you.

Comment: flush and close your writers

Comment: Just *close* them. @morgano close() implies flush().

Answer (score 1):

Get in the habit of creating all Writers, Readers, InputStreams and OutputStreams in [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statements.  It ensures they will be properly closed:

```
try (FileWriter edit = new FileWriter(chooser.getSelectedFile()+".txt")) {
    edit.write(editedFileText);
}
try (FileWriter srcFile = new FileWriter(chooser.getSelectedFile()+"_srcText"+".txt")) {
    srcFile.write(srcFileText);
}
try (FileWriter trans = new FileWriter(chooser.getSelectedFile()+"_translFile"+".txt")) {
    trans.write(translFileText);
}
```

If you're just writing a single String, you have the option of using [Files.write](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-byte%3aA-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-), which allows you to forego the use of a Writer altogether:

```
Files.write(Paths.get(chooser.getSelectedFile()+".txt"),
            editedFileText.getBytes());
Files.write(Paths.get(chooser.getSelectedFile()+"_srcText"+".txt"),
            srcFileText.getBytes());
Files.write(Paths.get(chooser.getSelectedFile()+"_translFile"+".txt"),
            translFileText.getBytes());
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `finally` to close the opened files, but first you need to declare them outside the `try catch finally`:

```
FileWriter edit,srcFile, trans;
edit = srcFile = trans = null;
try {
    edit = new FileWriter(chooser.getSelectedFile()+".txt");
    edit.write(editedFileText.toString());
    srcFile = new  FileWriter(chooser.getSelectedFile()+"_srcText"+".txt");
    srcFile.write(srcFileText.toString());
    trans = new FileWriter(chooser.getSelectedFile()+"_translFile"+".txt");
    trans.write(translFileText.toString());
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}finally{
    if(edit != null)
       edit.close();

    if(srcFile != null)
       srcFile.close();

    if(trans != null)
       trans.close();
}
```

Comment: The important thing here is 'close the opened files', which should have been stated first and separately. Can't see the wood for the trees as it is is.

Answer (score 0):

```
FileWriter writer=null;
        try {
             writer = new FileWriter(filename);
            writer.write(sb.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {

        } finally {
            if (writer != null)
                try {
                    writer.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
```